# Detect when a screenshot was taken without requiring storage permission on Android

Tags: android, permissions, storage, screenshot, detection

I want to know when a screenshot has been taken of our application, but I do not care about the metadata, nor do I want a reference to the actual image.

The current implementation I'm looking to improve declares a custom `ContentObserver`, which subscribes to `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`

```
mContentResolver.registerContentObserver(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, true, this)
```

This enables the Observer to be notified when content has changed in this URI.

```
@Override
synchronized public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
    super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
    if (uri.toString().startsWith(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString())) {
        try {
            checkPermissionAndProcess(uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.w(e, "onChange error : %s", e.toString());
        }
    } else {
        Timber.v("[Finish] not EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI ");
    }
}
```

At this point, we need to check if we have `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and if not, request it. If the user grants us this permission, we can verify if the URI change is a screenshot with a series of checks. If we don't have permission, a SecurityException is thrown.

```
private boolean matchPath(String path) {
    return (path.toLowerCase().contains("screenshots/") && !path.contains(FILE_POSTFIX));
}
```

My understanding of a ContentResolver observing `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` means that any changes external to the application's storage can invoke the `onChange` callback.

Is there any way around this without asking the user for storage access which feels icky?

On Android 7.1.1 and Android 13 devices, I have tried using the camera while the app is in the background to trigger the `onChange` of the `ContentResolver`, and I only see it invoked when I take a screenshot. Assuming just observing changes in `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` is naive, as other apps storing images could also result in changes here.

Comment: Dont post your problem referring to comments or threads. We will not follow them. Post the used and problematic code gher. And you even did not tell who took that screenshot.

Comment: @blackapps thanks for your comment. I have updated my post to remove references  to an existing post.